# Angular 2 pagination control with input - validation

Tags: angular, pagination, grid

I have a pagination component.

[image]

html:

            first_page

```
    <button md-mini-fab (click)="previous()" [disabled]="isFirstpageButtonDisabled" style="margin:0 0.5rem">
        <md-icon>chevron_left</md-icon>
    </button>
    <input #input type="text" (keyup.enter)="goToPage(input.value)" [(value)]="pageIndex" style="margin:0 0.5rem; width: 40px;">
    / {{totalPages}}
    <button md-mini-fab (click)="next()" [disabled]="isLastpageButtonDisabled" style="margin:0 0.5rem">
        <md-icon>chevron_right</md-icon>
    </button>

    <button md-mini-fab (click)="goToPage(totalPages)" [disabled]="isLastpageButtonDisabled" style="margin:0 0.5rem">
        <md-icon>last_page</md-icon>
    </button>
```

When user enters an invalid number/character in the input box, I display an error message. I also need to revert the input box value back to the previous number that was valid before.

```
checkPageIndex() {
    this.validpageIndex = true;    

    if (this.pageIndex < 1 || this.pageIndex > this.totalPages || isNaN(this.pageIndex)) {
        this.validpageIndex = false;
        this.toaster.showToaster('Please select a page between 1 and ' + this.totalPages + '.');
        return;
    }
}
```

I tried to achieve this by saving the previous page index and assigning that value once the valid check fails:

```
this.pageIndex = this.previousPageIndex;
```

This value is correctly getting assigned in the console log, but the input text box still shows the invalid input. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which ChangeDetectionStrategy do you have? Maybe you running outside of angular?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ChangeDetectionStrategy. Every time the input is a valid number, I set the this.previousPageIndex = this.pageIndex; I save the previous valid input so that I can use it again when an invalid input is entered.

Comment: To clarify further, I am using a simple variable binding between the input control and the component, like pageIndex: number in typescript,
 which is then bound to the value of the input control. <input #input type="text" (keyup.enter)="goToPage(input.value)" [(value)]="pageIndex" style="margin:0 0.5rem; width: 40px;">

Comment: Your approach would work if you saved the previousPageIndex every time you changed pageIndex, then on validation fail set pageIndex = previousPageIndex like you wrote. See my answer below for example working plunkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track just a couple things will get you there. Basically you'd want to keep track of lastPageIndex any time you change the current pageIndex, then when your check fails set the current pageIndex to the value from lastPageIndex. Also wouldn't hurt to change the input to an ngModel and add an on blur event for the textfield to capture their change if they leave. If your user might try to change the input to something else invalid you can add in checks against those, and even monitor the input using ngOnChanges() to be sure. An example updated goToPage function might look like

```
 goToPage(page: number) {
    // check to make sure number is valid
    if(this.pageIndex <= 1 || this.pageIndex >= this.pages.length || isNaN(this.pageIndex)) {
      alert("invalid page selected");
      this.pageIndex = this.lastPageIndex;
    }
    else {
      // update current page and save last index
      this.pageIndex = page;
      this.lastPageIndex = this.pageIndex;
    }
  }
```

And here's a simplified plunker with a working example of your questions http://plnkr.co/edit/EFBiVz4gy4nl4mFDe6x1?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker example looks exactly like what i need. When I try to do the same, I get this error: Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("       <input #input type="text" (keyup.enter)="goToPage(input.value)" (blur)=goToPage(input.value) [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="pageIndex">
        / {{totalPages}}

Comment: I figured it out. Had to import FormsModule  and this worked. Thank you so much!